# How to make a template contact form send to my email

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have been trying to figure this out all night, but nothing I try seems to be working.

I need to make it so this contact form will submit to my email address. What should I edit or create?

Here's my html code.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>

    <div class="content">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputName"><i class="icon-tag"></i></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="icon-inbox"></i></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" required>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group textarea">
          <label for="exampleInputMessage"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></label>
          <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" id="exampleInputMessage" placeholder="Write Message" required></textarea>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn color">SEND MESSAGE</button>
      </form>         
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is HIGHLY not recommended, but... `<form action="mailto:youraddress@example.com">....</form>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form action to a file that processes form data, if you don't know how try something like http://www.tectite.com/ (I'm not involved with them but they look OK at a glance.)

The better option is to host the form processor on your own server but that's a bit more technical.